# Create a mapping operation so each input element produces 1 or more output elements?

Tags: haskell

Recently I am trying to figure out how to do some programming in Haskell.

I'm trying to do some simple operations. Right now I'm stuck with an operation like in this example:

```
input = [1,2,3,4]
output = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
```

That is, for each element `x` in `input`, produce `x` elements of `x` in `output`. So, for element `1` in input, append `[1]` to output. Then, for element `2` in input, append elements `[2,2]` to output. Then, for element `3`, append `[3,3,3]`, etc. The algorithm should work only on standard numbers.

I know it's very easy, and it's trivial to perform it in "normal" imperative programming, but as Haskell's functions are stateless, I'm having a problem in how to approach this.

Could anyone please give me some hint how can an absolute Haskell beginner cope with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've just discovered monads!

Here's the general idea of what you're doing:

*For each `a`-element in the input (which is a container-type `M a`, here `[a]`), you specify an entire new container `M b`. But as a final result, you want just a single "flat" container `M b`.*

Well, let's take a look at the definition of the `Monad` type class:

```
class (Applicative m) => Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

which is exactly what you need. And lists are an instance of `Monad`, so you can write

```
replicates :: [Int] -> [Int]
replicates l = l >>= \n -> replicate n n
```

Alternatively, this can be written

```
replicates l = do
   n <- l
   replicate n n
```

---

It might be interesting to know that the, perhaps easier to understand, list comprehension

```
replicates l = [ n | n <- l, _ <- [1..n] ]
```

as suggested by chi, is actually just syntactic sugar for another monad expression:

```
     [ n | n <- l, _ <- [1..n] ] ≡ l >>= \n -> [1..n] >>= \_ -> return n
```

... or least it used to be in some old version of GHC, I think it now uses a more optimised implementation of list comprehensions. You can still turn on that de-sugaring variant with the `-XMonadComprehensions` flag.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another solution, exploiting list comprehensions:

```
output = [ n | n <- input , m <- [1..n] ]
```

Compare the above with the imperative Python code:

```
for n in input:            -- n <- input
   for m in range(1,n+1):  -- m <- [1..n]    (in Python the second extreme is excluded, hence +1)
      print n              -- the n in [ n | ... ]
```

Note that `m` is unused -- in Haskell it is customary to can call it `_` to express this:

```
output = [ n | n <- input , _ <- [1..n] ]
```

Answer (score 4):

As a beginner, I more easily understand something like this:

concat $ map (\x -> take x $ repeat x) [1,2,3,4]

For "list as monads" it is important to know that there is also "concat" operation under the hood (in bind definition), IMO

Comment: `take x $ repeat x` is just `replicate x x`. `concat $ map ...` is usually written as `concatMap ...`, or with list monad notation, `[1..4] >>= (\x-> replicate x x)` (the latter has a nice "processor" feel to it, but YMMV). The fanatics of pointfree might write the last one as [`[1..4] >>= join replicate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join).

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution:

```
rep (x:xs) = replicate x x ++ rep xs
rep [] = []
```

Hints:

- `replicate 5 "a"` gives `["a","a","a","a","a"]`, and it works the same way for any type in the second argument, but first argument must be of type Int
- the operator `++` concatenates two lists
- so the inferred type of `rep` is `[Int] -> [Int]`, if you need to use other types you should use conversion functions